# Unable to set constraints for custom UITableView Cell, created in xib as all data gets disappear on chage of size class

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints, xib

I'm not able to add constraints to UITableView Cell in an xcode 6.1 project. In my project, I have created custom table view cell in xib , as root view and loading that nib by using table view data source. Cell was created with size class "Any Width and Any Height"  and all required constraints were added.

[image: Any With Any Height]

Now I want to set constraints for iPhone in portrait mode. When I change the size class to "Compact Width and Regular Height" all of the sudden all UI controls of cell gets diaper from xib. Even those UI controls and constrains are visible in outline view (left side of editor area). In that case I can't add any constrains and even UI controls.

[image: Compact Width and Regular Height]

Is there any solution, so that I can add constraints in Cell.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a problem with version of XCode(6.1) I am using.

As it was very critical to find solution, I found temporary solution after trial and error.

- Select constraint that you want to modify.
- In Attribute Inspector add desired size class through (+) sign next to Constant value
- Set value that you want for this particular size class

[image]

For any constraint that you want only for specific size class then unchecked 'Installed' (at the end of Attribute Inspector for constraint) for Any Width and Any Height constant value.

This was temporary solution. I hope in upgraded XCode we can see contains of xib based table cell for various size class